# Why is this Dijkstra not working on directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, breadth-first-search, dijkstra

This dijkstra code isn't working for Directed graphs

For example for this testcase:

```
4 
2 
1
7
1 2 1
1 3 1
2 1 1
2 4 1
3 1 1
3 4 1
4 3 1
```

[Click to view Graph diagram for above testcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BysQU.png)

Edge 2 -> 4 is only one way while the algorithm behaves as if it is 2-way. Shortest path between 4 to 2 should be 3 while the following code gives 1 output :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int N = 1e5+10;
const int INF = 1e9+10;
vector<pair<int,int>> g[N];
vector<int> vis(N,0);
vector<int> dist(N, INF);


void bfs(int source){

    set<pair<int,int>> st;

    st.insert({0,source});
    dist[source] = 0;

    while(st.size()>0){
        auto curr = *st.begin();
        int wt_v = curr.first;
        int v = curr.second;
        st.erase(st.begin());

        if(vis[v]) continue;
        vis[v] = 1;
        
        for(auto child:g[v]){

            int child_v = child.first;
            int wt = child.second;

            if(dist[v] + wt < dist[child_v]){
                dist[child_v] = dist[v] + wt;
                st.insert({dist[child_v],child_v});
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    int n; cin>>n;
    int e; cin>>e;
    int t; cin>>t;
    int m; cin>>m;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        int v1,v2,wt; cin>>v1>>v2>>wt;
        g[v1].push_back({v2,wt});
    }

    bfs(e);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        cout<<dist[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a direct link from 2 to 4 with value 1, why *wouldn't* the shortest path from 2 to 4 be value 1?

Comment: Actually I need shortest path from 4 to 2. Not 2 to 4. I just edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 4 to 2, then you have to change your input.  The second line should be 4

As is, your output is hard to comprehend.  Lets's do this

```
bfs(e);

for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
    cout<<"dist from " << e << " to " <<i 
        << " is " <<dist[i]<<endl;
```

So now, input of this

```
4 
4
1
7
1 2 1
1 3 1
2 1 1
2 4 1
3 1 1
3 4 1
4 3 1
```

output is

```
dist from 4 to 1 is 2
dist from 4 to 2 is 3
dist from 4 to 3 is 1
dist from 4 to 4 is 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was just a conceptual mistake : /

Comment: Also known as an error.  You can avoid such errors by choosing meaningful variable names and documenting your code.